# how to remove a very special character in a df

Tags: r, regex

I have a df which have a special character in it. I would like to remove it but not sure how. I have tried `[:graph:]`, `[:print:]` and `<U+00AE>`. but nothing works. what should I do? Is it a way to remove similar problem in a dataset at once, such as `®`?

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(df = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Cabozantinib", 
"Left nephrectomy", "Left Superficial Inguinal Lymph Node Dissection", 
"XmAb<U+00AE>20717 (Duet-2 study - a humanized bispecific monoclonal antibody that binds PD1 and CTLA4)"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Perhaps `dplyr::mutate(df, df = stringr::str_remove(df, "\\x{00AE}"))` will work?

Comment: it may require some replacement and then conversion to print i.e. `library(stringi);stri_unescape_unicode(str_replace_all(df$df, "<U\\+([^>]+)\\>", "\\\\u\\1"));[1] "Cabozantinib"                                                                                   
[2] "XmAb®20717 (Duet-2 study - a humanized bispecific monoclonal antibody that binds PD1 and CTLA4)"...`

Comment: If I coverted to `®`, how should I remove that then? if I used `gsub("[[:print:]]", "",df$df  )`, then it remove all. In fact my raw data has  `®`. But when I read it into R, it changed it this strange charterer. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Stataq Wouldn't that be better to keep it as such with the symbol instead of removing it.

Comment: I ran into problem when I build wb and output the data again into excel.  I  tested many times and find out this is the record that stopped the file. Anyway to work around it?

Comment: @Stataq can you check the solution posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to remove those characters, use the pattern to match the `<U` followed by the `+` (metacharacter - escaped `\\`), followed by one or more characters that are not a `>` (`[^>]+`) and the `>` in `str_remove_all` to remove all occurence of that pattern substring

```
library(stringr)
df$df <- str_remove_all(df$df, "<U\\+[^>]+\\>")
df$df
[1] "Cabozantinib"                                                                                  
[2] "XmAb20717 (Duet-2 study - a humanized bispecific monoclonal antibody that binds PD1 and CTLA4)"
[3] "Left nephrectomy"                                                                              
[4] "Left Superficial Inguinal Lymph Node Dissection"
```

---

If we still want to print those unicode characters

```
library(stringi)
stri_unescape_unicode(str_replace_all(df$df, "<U\\+([^>]+)\\>", "\\\\u\\1"))
[1] "Cabozantinib"                                                                                   
[2] "XmAb®20717 (Duet-2 study - a humanized bispecific monoclonal antibody that binds PD1 and CTLA4)"
[3] "Left nephrectomy"                                                                               
[4] "Left Superficial Inguinal Lymph Node Dissection"
```

Comment: And just the briefest comment on the `[^>]` character class here for those beset by such 'this is the file they gave me...'

Comment: When I tried on my raw data, it now looks like `"XmAb<U+FFFD>20717 (Duet-2 study - a humanized bispecific monoclonal antibody that binds PD1 and CTLA4)"` and it won't change. Will `<U+xxx~ >` change every time when I read it?

Comment: @Stataq  Have you assigned the output back to the column i.e. `df$df <- ..`

Comment: @Stataq It does change .e. `str_remove_all("XmAb<U+FFFD>20717 (Duet-2 study - a humanized bispecific monoclonal antibody that binds PD1 and CTLA4)", "<U\\+[^>]+\\>")#
[1] "XmAb20717 (Duet-2 study - a humanized bispecific monoclonal antibody that binds PD1 and CTLA4)"`

Comment: Your codes works on df. df is a subset of my raw data set.

Comment: @Stataq It depends on whether you are updating the original data with the transformed data or not

Comment: @Stataq Probably, you have to do this on the full dataset

Comment: what if now I want to remove `<U+FFFD>`

Comment: @Stataq It does remove that part if you check the `str_remove_all` output Then, you may have to write the file back to update as a new file